# modifying select query before run with Sequelize hooks

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an `order` table that have one column called `time`
I store my timestamp as Integer in this filed
I have one query like this

```
Order.findAll(
                    {
                        where : {
                            time: {
                                [sequelize.Op.between]: ['2021/1/1', '2021/1/2']
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
```

my dates come from client side in normal format (not unix mode)
I want to modify my dates with beforeFind hook
I wrote this peace of code in my hook

```
hooks:{
        beforeFind(args, fn){
            console.log(args.where.time);
        }
}
```

but the result is

```
{ [Symbol(between)]: [ '2021/1/1', '2021/1/2'] }
```

how should i modify dates?
what is the key in this object?!

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer
I can access to my first date with

```
args.where.time[Sequelize.Op.between][0]
```

in my beforeFind hook